# Vending Machine Simulator that reads a file and uses arrays

Tags: java

So I am working on a program that mimics a real vending machine and I am having some troubles.  Here is the criteria for the program. It must,

- Read from a file that a user inputs.
- Once the file has been read display the items and prices for each.
- Assign a coordinate for each item just like a real vending machine (e.g A1, B3,         C4 etc.)
- Ask the user what item they want and have them input the coordinate.
- Then ask them to enter their money then give change or ask them to input more money.

I have figure out how to put the prices in an array and display them but that is as far as I have gotten. Please help! My code can be seen below!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Vending2 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
      System.out.print("Enter your food selection file: ");      // User inputs file
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                       // Keyboard input from user
      String filename = input.nextLine();
      Scanner fs = new Scanner(new File(filename));         // Scans in the file that was inputed



        String line;
        double price;
        int num = 0;
        while(fs.hasNextLine()){
             line = fs.nextLine();
             price = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[0]);
             num++;
        }

        fs.close();
        fs = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        double[] value = new double[num];                        //Array for prices
        int i = 0;
        while(fs.hasNextLine()){
             line = fs.nextLine();
             price = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[0]);
             value[i] = price;
             i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
  }
}
```

And below is the file I am reading from:

```
1.00 Honey roasted peanuts
1.50 Cheetos
1.50 Bugles
2.00 Synder’s Pretzels
1.00 Snickers
1.00 Twix
1.25 M n Ms
.75 Life savers
1.00 Twizzlers
1.00 Nutter Butters
1.00 Butter Fingers
1.50 King Size Kit Kats
1.25 Carrot sticks
.50 Juicy Fruit
.50 Spearmint Gum
0.50 Five gum
3.50 Pepperoni
1.75 Cheez-Its
.25 Slim Jim
1.50 Lays Barbeque Chips
```

Comment: What is your concrete question? "Please help" and "I am having some troubles" are much too vague.

Comment: Ok, the next step is to make a String array that is the same length as value, that contains the coordinates for each item. You might want to use a for loop (or two) for that.

Comment: Sorry, array probably isn't a good choice. What you should use is a HashMap if you've learned how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a class called FoodItem whcih contains Name and price

2) Split the line from file with "" and populate name & price

3) Add FoodItem to foodItemsList

4) Iterate through List and print the values.

I used the list assuming that there may be duplicates in food item names. If not, change List to HashMap.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Vending2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.print("Enter your food selection file: "); // User inputs
                                                                // file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Keyboard input from user
        String filename = input.nextLine();
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(new File(filename)); // Scans in the file that
                                                        // was inputed

        String line;
        double price;
        List<FoodItem> foodItemsList = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();

        while (fs.hasNextLine()) {
            line = fs.nextLine();
            String[] itemsWithPrice;
            itemsWithPrice = line.split(" ");
            if (itemsWithPrice.length > 1){
                price = Double.parseDouble(itemsWithPrice[0]);
                String name="";
                for (int i=1; i<itemsWithPrice.length;i++){
                    name +=     itemsWithPrice[i];              
                }
                foodItemsList.add(new FoodItem(name,price));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Food List");
        for (int i=0; i< foodItemsList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(foodItemsList.get(i));
        }
    }

}

class FoodItem{
    String name;
    double price;
    public FoodItem(String name, double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return new StringBuffer().append("name:").append(name).append(":").append("price:").append(price).toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

Enter your food selection file: v1.txt

Food List

```
name:Honeyroastedpeanuts:price:1.0
name:Cheetos:price:1.5
name:Bugles:price:1.5
name:SynderÆsPretzels:price:2.0
name:Snickers:price:1.0
name:Twix:price:1.0
name:MnMs:price:1.25
name:Lifesavers:price:0.75
name:Twizzlers:price:1.0
name:NutterButters:price:1.0
name:ButterFingers:price:1.0
name:KingSizeKitKats:price:1.5
name:Carrotsticks:price:1.25
name:JuicyFruit:price:0.5
name:SpearmintGum:price:0.5
name:Fivegum:price:0.5
name:Pepperoni:price:3.5
name:Cheez-Its:price:1.75
name:SlimJim:price:0.25
name:LaysBarbequeChips:price:1.5
```